# Are there an x64 installer of LINQPad?

Tags: linqpad

I have searched the site http://www.linqpad.net/ and haven't found an x64 installer.
I need it to launch code from my Visual Studio project that is x64.
I referenced an assembly from my project (via <kbd>F4</kbd>), and it is not getting loaded during runtime with BadImageFormatException.

Answer (score 2):

Download the **AnyCPU build** from http://www.linqpad.net/download.aspx.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for effort for building this useful tool.

Comment: But that build is not an installer.